# Import JSON into index.html from exported constant from external .js

Tags: javascript, json, web-component

I'm sure this is an easy fix. I'm trying to use an external .js file to store a list of JSON objects stored as string constants (see form-json.js below).

These JSON objects should be able to be imported by name into an index.html file that loads a web component in which the JSON is passed to the web component as an input.

When I hardcode the JSON directly to a const inside a script block (without the type="module" directive that's required for importing modules) inside the index.html file it works great. However, I'm getting undefined when I try to load the same JSON block from the imported .js module. My code is below:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Component!</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;700&family=Titillium+Web:wght@700&display=swap');
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body>
<my-form></my-form>
<script src="my-form.js" defer></script>
<script type="module">
    import {MY_SCHEMA_FORM} from './form-json.js';
    alert('the schema form is:', MY_SCHEMA_FORM); // empty
    let el = document.querySelector('my-form');
    el.formJson = MY_SCHEMA_FORM; // undefined from component @Input() formJson: string
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the angular elements component that loads the json and becomes `my-forms.js`

```
@Input() formJson: string;

myForm$: Observable<object>;

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    private hostListeners: HostListenerFacade
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this.formJson:', this.formJson); // UNDEFINED when loaded from an external .js
    const MY_SCHEMA_FORM = JSON.parse(this.formJson); // JSON.parse
    this.myForm$ = of(MY_SCHEMA_FORM).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('MY_SCHEMA_FORM:',MY_SCHEMA_FORM))
    )
}
```

form-json.js

```
export const MY_SCHEMA_FORM = "test";
```

Below test works if hardcoded into the index.html script block (but not as type="module"

```
<my-form></my-form>
<script>
    const MY_SCHEMA_FORM = 
    `{ 
    "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Address Example from Angular Virtual Conference",
    "description": "",
    "version": {
        "created": "10.3.6",
        "modified": "10.3.6"
    },
    "size": "",
    "properties": {
        "address-name": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "address-street": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "address-city": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "address-state1678730576920": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "address-zip": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "address-newsletter": {
        "type": [
            "boolean",
            "null"
        ]
        },
        "address-email": {
        "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "address-email"
    ],
    "rootWidgetClass": "  space-between",
    "externalFieldsEvent": "",
    "externalFieldsParams": [],
    "htmlWrapperClass": ""
    },
    "layout": [
    {
        "allowOverride": true,
        "appearance": "outline",
        "autocomplete": "off",
        "dataType": "text",
        "debounceCustomEventDelay": 0,
        "defaultField": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "floatLabel": "always",
        "panelWidth": " ",
        "htmlClass": "   ",
        "id": "1596465101826",
        "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
        "key": "address-name",
        "mandatoryField": false,
        "title": "Name",
        "title_revert": "Name",
        "type": "text"
    },
    {
        "name": "section1596465361207",
        "type": "div",
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-direction": "row",
        "justify-content": "space-between",
        "align-content": "stretch",
        "align-items": "stretch",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "expanded": true,
        "itemsLayoutCols": "col3",
        "itemsLayoutOutline": "true",
        "itemsLayoutWidth": "full-width",
        "htmlClass": "col3  outline full-width",
        "id": "1596465361207",
        "title": "Address Info",
        "items": [
        {
            "allowOverride": true,
            "appearance": "outline",
            "autocomplete": "off",
            "dataType": "text",
            "debounceCustomEventDelay": 0,
            "defaultField": true,
            "disabled": false,
            "floatLabel": "always",
            "panelWidth": " ",
            "htmlClass": "  full-width",
            "id": "1596465102653",
            "itemsLayoutWidth": "full-width",
            "key": "address-street",
            "mandatoryField": false,
            "title": "Street Address",
            "title_revert": "Street Address",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "allowOverride": true,
            "appearance": "outline",
            "autocomplete": "off",
            "dataType": "text",
            "debounceCustomEventDelay": 0,
            "defaultField": true,
            "disabled": false,
            "floatLabel": "always",
            "panelWidth": " ",
            "htmlClass": "   ",
            "id": "1596465103614",
            "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
            "key": "address-city",
            "mandatoryField": false,
            "title": "City",
            "title_revert": "City",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "allowOverride": true,
            "appearance": "outline",
            "approverEditable": true,
            "defaultField": true,
            "disabled": false,
            "floatLabel": "always",
            "htmlClass": "   ",
            "id": "1678730576921",
            "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
            "key": "address-state1678730576920",
            "mandatoryField": true,
            "title": "State",
            "title_revert": "State",
            "type": "select",
            "wruxDynamicParams": [
            {}
            ],
            "titleMap": [
            {
                "name": "Alabama",
                "value": "AL"
            },
            {
                "name": "Alaska",
                "value": "AK"
            },
            {
                "name": "American Samoa",
                "value": "AS"
            },
            {
                "name": "Arizona",
                "value": "AZ"
            },
            {
                "name": "Arkansas",
                "value": "AR"
            },
            {
                "name": "California",
                "value": "CA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Colorado",
                "value": "CO"
            },
            {
                "name": "Connecticut",
                "value": "CT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Delaware",
                "value": "DE"
            },
            {
                "name": "District Of Columbia",
                "value": "DC"
            },
            {
                "name": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
                "value": "FM"
            },
            {
                "name": "Florida",
                "value": "FL"
            },
            {
                "name": "Georgia",
                "value": "GA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Guam",
                "value": "GU"
            },
            {
                "name": "Hawaii",
                "value": "HI"
            },
            {
                "name": "Idaho",
                "value": "ID"
            },
            {
                "name": "Illinois",
                "value": "IL"
            },
            {
                "name": "Indiana",
                "value": "IN"
            },
            {
                "name": "Iowa",
                "value": "IA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Kansas",
                "value": "KS"
            },
            {
                "name": "Kentucky",
                "value": "KY"
            },
            {
                "name": "Louisiana",
                "value": "LA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Maine",
                "value": "ME"
            },
            {
                "name": "Marshall Islands",
                "value": "MH"
            },
            {
                "name": "Maryland",
                "value": "MD"
            },
            {
                "name": "Massachusetts",
                "value": "MA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Michigan",
                "value": "MI"
            },
            {
                "name": "Minnesota",
                "value": "MN"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mississippi",
                "value": "MS"
            },
            {
                "name": "Missouri",
                "value": "MO"
            },
            {
                "name": "Montana",
                "value": "MT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Nebraska",
                "value": "NE"
            },
            {
                "name": "Nevada",
                "value": "NV"
            },
            {
                "name": "New Hampshire",
                "value": "NH"
            },
            {
                "name": "New Jersey",
                "value": "NJ"
            },
            {
                "name": "New Mexico",
                "value": "NM"
            },
            {
                "name": "New York",
                "value": "NY"
            },
            {
                "name": "North Carolina",
                "value": "NC"
            },
            {
                "name": "North Dakota",
                "value": "ND"
            },
            {
                "name": "Northern Mariana Islands",
                "value": "MP"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ohio",
                "value": "OH"
            },
            {
                "name": "Oklahoma",
                "value": "OK"
            },
            {
                "name": "Oregon",
                "value": "OR"
            },
            {
                "name": "Palau",
                "value": "PW"
            },
            {
                "name": "Pennsylvania",
                "value": "PA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Puerto Rico",
                "value": "PR"
            },
            {
                "name": "Rhode Island",
                "value": "RI"
            },
            {
                "name": "South Carolina",
                "value": "SC"
            },
            {
                "name": "South Dakota",
                "value": "SD"
            },
            {
                "name": "Tennessee",
                "value": "TN"
            },
            {
                "name": "Texas",
                "value": "TX"
            },
            {
                "name": "Utah",
                "value": "UT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Vermont",
                "value": "VT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Virgin Islands",
                "value": "VI"
            },
            {
                "name": "Virginia",
                "value": "VA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Washington",
                "value": "WA"
            },
            {
                "name": "West Virginia",
                "value": "WV"
            },
            {
                "name": "Wisconsin",
                "value": "WI"
            },
            {
                "name": "Wyoming",
                "value": "WY"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "allowOverride": true,
            "appearance": "outline",
            "autocomplete": "off",
            "dataType": "text",
            "debounceCustomEventDelay": 0,
            "defaultField": true,
            "disabled": false,
            "floatLabel": "always",
            "panelWidth": " ",
            "htmlClass": "   ",
            "id": "1596465235450",
            "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
            "key": "address-zip",
            "mandatoryField": false,
            "title": "Zip",
            "title_revert": "Zip",
            "type": "text"
        }
        ],
        "defaultField": false,
        "mandatoryField": false,
        "allowOverride": true
    },
    {
        "allowOverride": true,
        "color": "primary",
        "customCSS": "top-margin-none",
        "defaultField": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "htmlClass": " top-margin-none  ",
        "id": "1596465446273",
        "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
        "key": "address-newsletter",
        "mandatoryField": false,
        "title": "Newsletter?",
        "title_revert": "Newsletter?",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "wruxDynamicParams": [
        {}
        ],
        "customDataType": "boolean",
        "truthyValue": "true",
        "falsyValue": "false",
        "defaultValue": "false"
    },
    {
        "allowOverride": true,
        "appearance": "outline",
        "approverEditable": true,
        "defaultField": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "floatLabel": "always",
        "htmlClass": "   ",
        "id": "1596465231494",
        "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
        "key": "address-email",
        "mandatoryField": true,
        "title": "Remote Employees Email Lookup",
        "title_revert": "State",
        "type": "select",
        "wruxDynamic": true,
        "wruxDynamicHook": "getEndpoint",
        "wruxDynamicParams": [
        {
            "name": "_endpoint",
            "value": "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
        },
        {
            "name": "_labelKey",
            "value": "username"
        },
        {
            "name": "_valueKey",
            "value": "email"
        }
        ],
        "validationMessages": {
        "required": "Required"
        },
        "logic": {
        "00|do": {
            "00|something": "address-newsletter",
            "01|=:boolean": true,
            "02|show": true
        }
        }
    }
    ],
    "data": {}
}`;
    let el = document.querySelector('my-form');
    el.formJson = MY_SCHEMA_FORM;
</script>
```

Comment: You're importing `MY_SCHEMA_FORM` but then trying to use `UNITY_SCHEMA_FORM`?

Comment: Typo in my question. The imported constant is undefined the way I'm trying to do it.

Comment: The problem here appears to be that when the MY_SCHEMA_FORM content is loaded from the external.js, it is still undefined when the `my-form.js` is loaded and so that angular element's script the `@Input() jsonForm` is still undefined. Even though that script is deferred and even if I place `form-json.js` in the head section.

Answer (score 1):

Like commented the variable is named `MY_SCHEMA_FORM`.

```html
<my-form></my-form>
<script src="my-form.js" defer></script>
<script type="module">
    import {MY_SCHEMA_FORM} from 'data:text/javascript;base64,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';
    let el = document.querySelector('my-form');
    el.formJson = MY_SCHEMA_FORM;
    console.log('the schema form is:', el.formJson);
</script>
```

Comment: I've updated my example to show how it works if I hardcode the form JSON constant inside the inline script. However, when I try to load it through the `type="module"` script from the external .js it fails.